# Cleaner way of writing this

Tags: php

What would be the most efficient way to write the following code in php:

```
<?php

if($result === 1) {
    echo "<img src=\"1.png\" alt=\"1\" />";
} else if ($result === 2) {
    echo "<img src=\"1.png\" alt=\"1\" /><img src=\"2.png\" alt=\"2\" />";
} else if ($result === 3) {
    echo "<img src=\"1.png\" alt=\"1\" /><img src=\"2.png\" alt=\"2\" /><img src=\"3.png\" alt=\"3\" />";
}  else if ($result === 4) {
    echo "<img src=\"1.png\" alt=\"1\" /><img src=\"2.png\" alt=\"2\" /><img src=\"3.png\" alt=\"3\" /><img src=\"4.png\" alt=\"4\" />";
}

?>
```

Can something with loops be done so that all the images show in their correct order? Thank you.

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Side note: use single quotes around your strings so you don't have to escape the double quotes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about something like

```
$str = '';
for ($i = 1; $i <= $result; $i++) {
  $str.= "<img src=\"{$i}.png\" alt=\"{$i}\" />";
}
echo $str;  // if you want to print the resulting string.
```

Update: to be technically accurate, you should put `$result = min($result, 4);` at the beginning to exactly match your example. I'm not sure how exact your example was, though.

Answer (score 4):

```
$template = '<img src="%d.png" alt="%d" />';

$result = 3;

$html = implode('', array_map(function($d) use($template) {
    return sprintf($template, $d, $d);
}, range(1, $result)));

var_dump($html);
```

Comment: You might want to use `array_walk()` instead, dropping `implode()` and changing `sprintf()` to `printf()`. https://eval.in/69220 :)

Comment: @Paulo Freitas: generally algorithms shouldn't produce any output. So I see more harm than good

Comment: If this was a function that returns something, I would've agreed with you... :P It's all about choices.

Answer (score 2):

Create a switch structure: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php

```
switch ($result) {
case 1:
    echo "...";
    break;
case 2:
    echo "...";
    break;
```

etc.

Comment: Also, you could use single quotes instead of \"

Comment: This could work but you'd want to leave out the `break;` statements. That would force PHP to execute each statement following one successful match, producing the desired result of echoing ***all*** the images. In it's current form, you are going to echo ***one*** image.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `if else` to continue concatenating (adding to) the html string, rather than repeating yourself.

Answer (score 2):

I think the most efficient would be:

```
echo substr("<img src=\"1.png\" alt=\"1\" /><img src=\"2.png\" alt=\"2\" /><img src=\"3.png\" alt=\"3\" /><img src=\"4.png\" alt=\"4\" />", 0, 27 * $result);
```